# If the sequence $a_n$ converges to $1$ then $a_{n+1}+\frac{1}{n}$ also converges to $1$

Tags: calculus, analysis

The definition I have for convergence of a sequence $a_n$ to $p$ is that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$|a_n-p|<\epsilon\text{ for all } n>N$$ and I was just wondering if it was possible to say that $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$ and $a_{n+1}$ converges to $1$ but then again I'm not sure how to formally state that? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

1. It is true that if $a_n$ converges to $a$ and $b_n$ converges to
   $b$, then $a_n+b_n$ converges to $a+b$.
2. It is also true that if $a_n$ converges to $a$ then all of its
   subsequences converge to $a$, in particular, $a_{n+1}$ must converge
   to $a$ as well.

For the above, you may need to prove or cite from your book.

In your case, since $a_n$ converges to $1$, then it follows that $a_{n+1}$ converges to $1$ as well by (by 2). Additionally, since $1/n$ converges to 0 then the sum $a_{n+1}+1/n$ must converge to $1+0$ (by 1).

**Method 2**

Alternatively, you could prove this directly (though you wouldn't do this in practice) as follows:

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Because $a_n$ converges to 1, we know there exists an $N_1$ such that $|a_n-1|<\epsilon/2$ whenever $n> N_1$, so in particular, $|a_{n+1}-1|<\epsilon/2$. Next choose $N_2$ to be large enough so that $1/N_2<\epsilon/2$. Finally, define $N=\max\{N_1, N_2\}$. It follows that if $n>N$ then by the triangle inequality,
$$
|a_{n+1}+1/n-1|\leq |a_{n+1}-1|+|1/n|<\epsilon/2 +\epsilon/2=\epsilon
$$
And so $a_{n+1}+1/n$ converges to 1 as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sum theorem for limits.  Or if you don't have that yet, you can find $N_1$ so that $|a_n-p|<\epsilon/2$ $\forall$ $n\geq N_1$ and find $N_2$ so that $|\frac1n|<\epsilon/2$ $\forall$ $n\geq N_2$.  Let $N$ be the max of $N_1$ and $N_2$.  Then for $n\geq N$ you can show $|a_{n+1}+\frac1n - p|<\epsilon$ by using the triangle inequality for absolute values.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a sequence $a_n$ converges, say $a_n \to \ell$, and consider the sequence $b_n = a_{n+1}$.

Does $b_n$ converge? Let's see, by definition, given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that $|a_n - \ell| < \epsilon$ whenever $n > N$. In particular, if $n > N$ then $|b_n - \ell| = |a_{n+1} - \ell| < \epsilon$ (because $n + 1 > n > N$). Therefore, $b_n \to \ell$.

As for the sequence $c_n = \frac{1}{n}$, does it converge to $0$? Well, if $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ then $\left|\frac{1}{n} - 0 \right| = \left|\frac{1}{n} \right| < \epsilon$. So, given $\epsilon > 0$, can you find an appropriate $N$?